# How to update state from seperate classes?

Tags: flutter

I currently have 3 Widgets to create the main page of my app. The first, body.dart, is where the majority of my main page resides. It uses receives a screenType to resize the screen based on what the size of the device is. This works fine, but I want to add the ability to sort the data in the body.dart. But the button to initiate this change resides in another class, home.dart. Between the two is a ResponsiveLayout class which handles figuring out the screen size and calling the Body constructor with the screen size.

Here are my classes:

body.dart:

```dart
class Body extends StatefulWidget {
  final service = IsarService();
  final int screenType;
  Body({super.key, required this.screenType});

  @override
  State<Body> createState() => _BodyState();
}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {
  Sort _s = Sort.desc;
  SortField _sortField = SortField.name;

  void _changeSort(Sort s) {
    setState(() {
      _s = s;
    });
  }

  void _changeSortField(SortField sortField) {
    setState(() {
      _sortField = sortField;
    });
  }

  ScreenSize _getScreenSize(context) {
    switch (widget.screenType) {
      case 0:
        return ScreenSize(
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.4,
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.325,
            100.0,
            10.0);
      case 1:
        return ScreenSize(
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.325,
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.425,
            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.325,
            100.0,
            10.0);
      default: //desktop
        return ScreenSize(200.0, 320.0, 200.0, 100.0, 12.0);
    }
  }

  late ScreenSize screenSize;
  late Offset tapXY;
  late RenderBox overlay;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    screenSize = _getScreenSize(context);
    overlay = Overlay.of(context).context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: StreamBuilder<List<Plant>>(
              stream: widget.service.listenToPlantsWithSort(_s, _sortField), //I want to change _s and _sortField from home.dart
              builder: (context, snapshot) => Wrap(
                children: snapshot.hasData
                    ? snapshot.data!.map((plant) {
                        return InkWell(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                          onTapDown: getPosition,
                          onLongPress: () => showMenu(
                            context: context,
                            position: relRectSize,
                            items: <PopupMenuEntry>[
                              PopupMenuItem(
                                child: const Text('Edit'),
                                onTap: () => {},
                              ),
                              PopupMenuItem(
                                child: const Text('Delete'),
                                onTap: () =>
                                    {widget.service.deletePlant(plant.id)},
                              ),
                            ],
                            useRootNavigator: false,
                          ),
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Card(
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      Container(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: const Color.fromARGB(
                                              255, 161, 160, 159),
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                                        ),
                                        child: ConstrainedBox(
                                          constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                            maxWidth: screenSize.imgMaxWidth,
                                            maxHeight: screenSize.imgMaxHeight,
                                          ),
                                          child: ClipRRect(
                                              borderRadius:
                                                  BorderRadius.circular(3),
                                              child: plant.image!.length > 1
                                                  ? Image.memory(
                                                      Uint8List.fromList(
                                                          plant.image!),
                                                      fit: BoxFit.cover)
                                                  : Image.asset(
                                                      'assets/img/test.jpg',
                                                      fit: BoxFit.cover)),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                          maxWidth: screenSize.tagsMaxWidth,
                                          maxHeight: screenSize.tagsMaxHeight,
                                        ),
                                        child: CardTags(
                                          plant: plant,
                                          fontSize: screenSize.fontSize,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList()
                    : [],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

responsive_layout.dart:

```dart
class ResponsiveLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  ResponsiveLayout({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      double width = constraints.maxWidth;
      switch (width) {
        case < 400:
          return Body(screenType: ScreenType.mobile.index);
        case < 600:
          return Body(screenType: ScreenType.tablet.index);
        default:
          return Body(screenType: ScreenType.desktop.index);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

home.dart (Where I want to be able to change the state of Body):

```dart
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  void _showSimpleModalDialog(context) {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return const CreatePlantForm();
        });
  }

  HomePage({super.key});

  SortField sortField = SortField.name;
  Sort s = Sort.desc;

  final service = IsarService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width.toString()),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).push(
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const SettingsScreen(),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_alt),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_list_rounded),
            onPressed: () {
              s == Sort.desc ? s = Sort.asc : s = Sort.desc;
              //Where I want to redraw the Body
              print(s);
            },
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () {
              service.deleteDB();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ResponsiveLayout(),

      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => {
          //open modal
          _showSimpleModalDialog(context)
        },
        tooltip: 'Add Plant',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), 
    );
  }
}
```

I tried looking at examples but many of them are one class to another, and I'm not sure how that applies in my case since I have the ResposiveLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using [riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod) to create providers for both the s and sortField. Code below:

```dart
final sProvider = StateProvider<Sort>((ref) => Sort.desc);
final sortFieldProvider = StateProvider<SortField>((ref) => SortField.name);
```

And then I changed the onPressed of the sort button in the Home widget to:

```dart
onPressed: () {
  ref.watch(sProvider) == Sort.desc
    ? ref.read(sProvider.notifier).state = Sort.asc
    : ref.read(sProvider.notifier).state = Sort.desc;
  print(ref.watch(sProvider));
},
```

Finally, I changed Body from a stateful widget to extend ConsumerWidget and could then access the providers from my stream:

```dart
stream: service.listenToPlantsWithSort(ref.watch(sProvider), ref.watch(sortFieldProvider))
```